# Using R Regex to identify two characters followed by a dash and two numbers

Tags: r, regex

Very obnoxious regex question incoming! I have a column that I am trying to split into two based off a condition. I'd like a new column to be created when there are two characters, followed by a dash and two numbers (e.g., `CA-01`).

My code is:

`mydf %>% extract(col = pilot_id, regex = "[a-z]{2}.d{2}", into = 'facility_test')`

Where the column I'd like to identify the pattern in is `pilot_id`, and the new column I'd like to make is `facility_test`.

Comment: Try with `"\\b[A-Za-z]{2}-\\d{2}\\b"`. You have a typo, `d` only matches `d`, you need `\d` to match digits.

Comment: Let's say a value in `pilot_id` is `TGT Track -FL-03 (Hilsborough County) 3/3/2021`.

Comment: 2 letters AA, a dash -, then 2 numbers 44. Is this the type of source you need to match with a regex ? Pretty standard [a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9]. Is that the question. Looks more than simple right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to capture in `extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>%
  extract(col = pilot_id,  regex = ".*-([A-Z]{2}-\\d{2})\\s.*", 
     into = 'facility_test')

# A tibble: 1 x 1
#    facility_test
#  <chr>        
#1 FL-03
```

#### data

```
mydf <- tibble(pilot_id = "TGT Track -FL-03 (Hilsborough County) 3/3/2021")
```

Comment: When I use this, the column is filled with N/As. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: @wcbrown there was a typo in my code.  I forgot to add `\\` before the `d{2}`